# Webmatrix starter site - new users require email confirmation

Tags: security, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I have built my site based around the user management that comes with the starter site template. This works very well, except i need to modify it slightly for my use case. Let me explain:

Currently, when a new user registers, the user is created in the database, but does not let users access any pages that are secured using "WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser();" until they open and click a confirmation email....

I want to allow users access to certain parts of my site before they confirm their email, is this possible?

Should i be using a different method to WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser()?
Should i be removing the "requireEmailConfirmation" switch when creating the user??

Currently, it looks like this:

```
                try {
                bool requireEmailConfirmation = !WebMail.SmtpServer.IsEmpty();
                var token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, requireEmailConfirmation);
                if (requireEmailConfirmation) {
                    var hostUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
                    var confirmationUrl = hostUrl + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/owner/confirm?confirmationCode=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token));

                    var details = "X-MC-MergeVars: {\"FIRSTNAME\": \"" + firstname + "\", \"LASTNAME\": \"" + lastname + "\", \"CONFIRMADDRESS\": \"" + confirmationUrl + "\"}";
                    var header = new[]{"X-MC-Template:registertemplate", "Reply-To:noreply@stayinflorida.co.uk", details};

                    WebMail.Send(
                        to: email,
                        subject: "Please confirm your account",
                        body: "Your confirmation code is: " + token + ". Visit <a href=\"" + confirmationUrl + "\">" + confirmationUrl + "</a> to activate your account.",
                        additionalHeaders: header
                    );
                }

                if (requireEmailConfirmation) {
                    // Thank the user for registering and let them know an email is on its way
                    Response.Redirect("~/owner/thanks");
                } else {
                    // Navigate back to the homepage and exit
                    WebSecurity.Login(email, password);

                    Response.Redirect("~/");
                }
            } catch (System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException e) {
                ModelState.AddFormError(e.Message);
            }
```

Comment: How are you preventing these users from accessing pages that you want them to be able to access prior to confirming their registration?

Comment: Hi Mike, currently all my "owner" pages are protected using the WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); method. But from testing, this only works once a user has confirmed their account via email.

Comment: What i want to achieve, is instead of waiting for them to confirm their email, they still get access to certain pages prior to confirmation. The problem is, i need to do some SQL calls on these pages using the WebSecurity.CurrentUserId; method, which i can only do once a user is logged in right?

Comment: Yes. If you require the user to be authenticated, they must have a valid account and be logged in. You can get round it by getting the user to log in in order to identify them. However, your login form for these pages will not make use of the WebSecurity helper. You will query the database directly instead - just to validate the fact that they have tried to register.

Answer (score 0):

for pages they must be registered to use 
This goes at the top

```
@{
    if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login?returnUrl="
            + "~/AllRaces.cshtml");
    }

    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Upcoming";
}
```

For pages anyone can look at
this goes at the top

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Contact";
}
```